# Using HTML5 Geo Location to move the marker and update the position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I have implemented the following HTML5 geo location script.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_map_script

Can someone please explain how I can generate the map so that the marker can be dragged to a new position and the latitude/longitude position updated?

I have implemented a website using this script but the results are not always accurate. Sometimes I assume the GPS signal is weak so it then returns the location of the nearest phone mast I guess. What I want is for the user to be able to update their position to make it more accurate so that I can then submit their lat/long position. Perhaps what is needed here is the ability to add another marker.